# Nautilus - no preference .. on ubuntu GNOME 14.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 14.10, appmenu, preferences

im using Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 
i cant find Nautilus preferences in nautilus window, where i can change things like showing folders in list view as default , and such things... i checked some asked questions here but nothing worked so far... any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Preferences are actually under a menu at the top of the gnome window, not attached to the nautilus  window.  Please see my attached screenshot for an example

[image]